# Districts/Sublocalities: List of, or how to get using Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, states, regions, countries

I am desperately trying to find a list/database of districts or sublocalities for all cities of the world.

I use the list of all cities of the world from maxmind.com, however, they do not provide sublocalities or districts (like e.g. "Manhattan", "Brooklyn", ... in New York).

Does anybody know if there exists a solution out there somewhere? Or is there a posibility to get all sublocalities using Google Maps API? (As I have 2.7mio cities with LatLng values in the database).

Thank you very much in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

Bulk downloads of Google data are forbidden by the Terms of Service.

Geonames is probably your best bet, although neighbourhoods are only available directly for US cities:
http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#neighbourhood

[Children](http://www.geonames.org/export/place-hierarchy.html#children) of existing Geonames objects are available, but that doesn't appear to include children of cities.

Comment: thank you for you answer Andrew... I've already been to this site, although I would really need for all major cities worldwide... anyway, I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: concerning google: bulk downloads yes, however, if I e.g. wanted to show a marker for each neighborhood of a city on a map, this would be legal, right?

Comment: Up to a point. You shouldn't store that data permanently. And it's not necessarily easy to get that data without it being potentially classed as a bulk download. At your own risk, I think!

Comment: well, OK... even if I don't store them permanently, is there any way to get neighborhoods per city with google API? it is included in the json or xml response (sublocality, political), but only for a certain address/latlng value...