# List of Cities in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know if there is a way to get a list of cities that are recognized by Google Maps?  I've been searching around and can't seem to find any available/updated list...

Comment: I doubt it... they don't want people mining their data. What are you trying to do with it? Maybe there's some other way to accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question: [Districts/Sublocalities: List of, or how to get using Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213019/districts-sublocalities-list-of-or-how-to-get-using-google-api) tl;dr -- forbidden by the TOS, but there are alternatives.